# if(result == NULL) is returning false always even when the query returns zero rows

Tags: c++, cassandra

I am using the Cassandra C++ driver in my application. I am observing many crashes. After debugging I identified that even when the query output is zero rows , the `if (result == NULL)` is `false` and when I iterate through the result, one place or other it is crashing. Below is the code sample. Please suggest me any solution for this.

```
const char* query = "SELECT variable_id, variable_name FROM aqm_wfvariables WHERE template_id = ?;";
    CassError rc = CASS_OK;
    CassSession* session = NULL;

    if((session=CassandraDbConnect::getInstance()->getSessionForCassandra())==NULL){
            return false;
    }

    CassStatement* statement = cass_statement_new(query, 1);
    cass_statement_bind_int32(statement, 0, wf_template_id );
    CassFuture* query_future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
    cass_future_wait(query_future);

    rc = cass_future_error_code(query_future);
    if (rc != CASS_OK) {
            logMsg(DEBUG, 7, "cass_session_execute failed for query #%d:%s:%s", 1, __FILE__, query);
            cass_statement_free(statement);
            return false;
    }
    cass_statement_free(statement);
    const CassResult* result = cass_future_get_result(query_future);

    if (result == NULL) {
            cass_future_free(query_future);
            logMsg(DEBUG, 7, "No values are returned for  query #%d:%s:%s", 1, __FILE__, query);
            return false;
            }
    cass_future_free(query_future);

    CassIterator* row_iterator = cass_iterator_from_result(result);

    while (cass_iterator_next(row_iterator)) {

            const CassRow* row = cass_iterator_get_row(row_iterator);

            /* Copy data from the row */
```

Comment: It seems there's a difference between a return of NULL, which presumably means the function failed, and a return of a result with zero matching records.

Comment: Is there any way to know the number of rows contained the result .. I mean if I can know that there are zero rows in the result.. I will not iterate through the result at all and I can avoid the crashes

Comment: @NarayanaVasa: If written properly, an iteration over an empty collection does not crash. Even more important, an iteration that crashes on an empty collection probably has a one-off error that also affects non-empty collections.

Comment: But the line where the crash happening is this: "while (cass_iterator_next(row_iterator)) {"  And that happens for the first time itself when the line is executed

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
 (result.cass_result_row_count>0)
```

instead of

```
   (result == NULL)
```

to verify if query returns zero rows. In your code, `result` is always an instance of `CassResult` and not a null reference when zero rows are returned.